# Bootstrap carousel - how increase only the height

Tags: css

Im having a CSS issue with boostrap carousel

I just want to make it higher, i've tried several css and nothing worked. The code is
in this jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Et4pc

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
       ....
 </div>
```

Comment: What have you actually tried. I don't see the CSS that you used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the height of the images in your carousel via CSS:

```
.carousel img {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Et4pc/50/. However, if you want to cut the image on the side, try the following (this will cut the image on the right):

```
.carousel {
    width: 400px;
}
.carousel img {
    height: 500px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Et4pc/52/. Try adding `margin-left:-50%;` to cut off the images on both sides.

Comment: Or do you want to increase the height of the carousel and cut of the images on the left and right?